# Is the Ariane 5 rolled out or is the hangar moved away?

Tags: launchpad, ariane

Ariane 5 rockets (like the one carrying the JWST) are assembled upright in a hangar, but during the launch (obviously) the hangar is no longer around the rocket. Does the Ariane 5 roll out of the assembly hangar? Or is the hangar moved away from the Ariane 5?

I recently saw a mockup of an Ariane 4 where the hangar got rolled away from the launchpad and the rocket stayed in place. Is this still the case for Ariane 5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Ariane 5 is moved from the **BAF** (FR: Bâtiment d’Assemblage Final, EN: Final Assembly Building) to the launch pad:

[image: Ariane 5 moving from BAF]

[image: Annotated wide view]

There is no encapsulation facility at the launch pad, which is "approximately 2600 m*" from the BAF.

*measuring with google maps gives 2.60 kilometers.

Sources:

- [Ariane 5 User’s Manual, Issue 5 Revision 3](https://www.arianespace.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Ariane5-users-manual-Jun2020.pdf), also available from [main Ariane 5 webpage](https://www.arianespace.com/vehicle/ariane-5/)
- [Ariane 5 Brochure](https://www.arianespace.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Arianespace_Brochure_Ariane5_Sept2019.pdf), also available from [main Ariane 5 webpage](https://www.arianespace.com/vehicle/ariane-5/)